# pandas to_csv creating problem for string &quot;test123&quot; hello world

Tags: pandas

reading CSV files and concatenate files and then creating one single CSV file using data frame passed to pandas to_csv function below code shows

```
csv_buffer = StringIO()
data.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
s3_resource.Object(bucket, path_save_report+report_name).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

output CSV file

```
test123&quot       hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using a trick, actually, it's a problem with Linux Libre office application while reading the file, latest version gives this problem (Version: 6.0.7.3). The problem is while opening libre office application default uses column separated by ';'.

To solve this I have added escapechar parameter in to_csv ([info](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)) to ignore ; below updated code.

```
data.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False, escapechar=';', encoding='utf-8')
```